# Postgresql: Get maximum value out of temporary table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

So i need to get the the maximum out of this given temporary table:

```
 WITH country_sold AS ( 
   SELECT l.country, sum(r.sold) as count 
   FROM Label as l, released as r 
   WHERE l.label_name = r.label_name  
   GROUP BY l.country
 )
```

Requesting `SELECT * FROM country_sold;`
gives back:

```
Country Sold

USA     3232322
England 1232
```

The question is now, how do i get the maximum value out of this temporary table (obviously thats USA with the higher sold pieces in this case)?

I tried:

`SELECT max(sold) FROM country_sold;`

and it gives me the maximum number back (the value from USA), but how i can i also retrieve the country? When i try to use

```
SELECT country, max(sold) FROM country_sold GROUP BY country;
```

but this will just give me back the initial result from country_sold, just with a different column name, as showed above:

```
Country max

USA     3232322
England 1232
```

What am i missing?

Thanks in advance everyone!

Comment: `with` does not define a "temporary table". It's called a common table expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Just use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`:

```
WITH country_sold AS (
      SELECT l.country, sum(r.sold) as count
      FROM Label l JOIN
           released r 
           ON l.label_name = r.label_name
      GROUP BY l.country
     )
SELECT cs.*
FROM country_sold cs
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

You also don't need a subquery or CTE for this:

```
      SELECT l.country, sum(r.sold) as count
      FROM Label l JOIN
           released r 
           ON l.label_name = r.label_name
      GROUP BY l.country
      ORDER BY count DESC
      LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Your solution works by the way, i will accept it once am able to do so (have to wait several minutes). Thanks for taking your time! If you don't mind the question about commas, would like to hear more, only if you don't bother. Don't have to be super in detail. Thanks!

Comment: @Prometheus . . . Commas are an archaic syntax for joining tables.  Proper `JOIN` syntax became available in the 1990s.  Most people think it is easier to read (the `JOIN` conditions are part of the `JOIN` operator).  More importantly, explicit `JOIN`s are more powerful because they support outer joins.

Answer (score 1):

See [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/tutorial-agg.html) the example in the postgresql docs:

```
SELECT city FROM weather
WHERE temp_lo = (SELECT max(temp_lo) FROM weather)
```

This is exactly what you are looking for:

```
SELECT country FROM country_sold
WHERE sold = (SELECT max(sold) FROM country_sold)
```